# Vector Layer editing in OpenLayers2

Tags: openlayers-2, editing, features

I can draw a polygon in `OpenLayers` by running this code.

```
        var points = [];

        var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(0, 0);
        point.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913');
        points.push(point);

        var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(0, 30);
        point.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913');
        points.push(point);

        var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(30, 30);
        point.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913');
        points.push(point);

        var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(30, 0);
        point.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913');
        points.push(point);

        var ring = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(points);
        var polygon = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([ring]);

        // create some attributes for the feature
        var attributes = { name: "my name", bar: "foo" };

        var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(polygon, attributes);
        select.addFeatures([feature]);

        map.addLayer(select);
```

My map can show this polygon perfectly. Here I did `point.transform` to match my map's projection system.

Now I want to edit this polygon like `'DragFeature', 'SelectFeature', 'Separator', 'DrawHole', 'ModifyFeature' etc` by `OpenLayers`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The best place to look is the online OpenLayers [examples](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/)

Here's an example of creating and modifying [shapes](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/modify-feature.html).

Comment: Thanks, I used [OpenLayers Editor](https://github.com/geops/ole) and it works fine.